# React - passing state value from one component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[ 14

2
I have two components SignIn and RmView(two are in different js files). in SignIn i am calling the api and settint the component state . I have to pass an state values to RmView component through app component).][1](https://i.stack.imgur.co)

[this is the code of app.js here i want to get the state of sign in component and pass to rm component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGQBh.png)m/WiQxE.png

Comment: please don put external links and post the relevant code snippet here. Also pass you data as props.

Comment: Your question should be self-contained, please read a section on how to ask good questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can pass data through props, but your question is not clear please post relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question it's not clear and without code it's really hard to help you, but i will say that you should look to implement [redux](https://redux.js.org/) to share this data from the api with the different parts of your app

Comment: this is better posted as a comment.